# Distribute 5V 16A over Multiple PCBs: One Cable

Tags: power

I want to power a set of WS2818B ([datasheet](http://www.world-semi.com/solution/details-140-4.html)) and White LEDs ([datasheet](https://lcsc.com/product-detail/Light-Emitting-Diodes-LED_HONGLITRONIC-Hongli-Zhihui-HONGLITRONIC-HL-AM-2835H421W-S1-08-HR6-SDCM-6-3800K-4250K-60mA_C516132.html)).
18 RGB and 9 White LEDs will be mounted to seperat PCB Modules, for which I calculated 0.648A and 0.8A  per Panel. Though I am planning on running the white leds on half brightness with PWM and only when 2 of the 3 RGB channels are of, which should reduce the required current for when the white LEDs are in use. I would like to run a Powerwire for the WS2818B Leds and one the White Leds, so that I can use PWM. I could of course power form multiple points, but that wouldn't be suitable for my case.

How would I safely transfer the power required for at least 21 Modules, which is around 16A when accounted for 80% Power Supply use, without multiple connection points or 2cm wide PCB traces?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119999/discussion-on-question-by-jannis-distribute-5v-16a-over-multiple-pcbs-one-cable).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At some point you'll realize that distributing 5V is complicated and expensive due to physics,:

A 16 A supply is expensive. Connectors rated for that current are expensive, too. You need thick copper. Everything becomes bulky, and you still see voltage drops.

A simple cheap Buck converter on each of your modules will allow you to do the distribution at e.g. roughly 12V, and have proportionally less current, and thus less losses, which atop of everything you care less about, since anything sufficiently above the LED supply voltage still works.

You'll be able to use a lower voltage than your 5V, too:

Your rgb LEDs only need 3.7V. You don't specify how you're planning to control your white LEDs, but both putting multiple in series as well as multiplexing them to a single constant current buck would work and reduce your wasted power.

Comment: Could I also use an even higher voltage, let's say 24V?

Comment: Sure. But at some point the Buck converters and their inductors become more complex or harder to insulate and hence expensive.

Comment: WS2812 need 5V, not 3.7.  Minimum 4V.

Comment: @usrr263983 I was adhering to the data sheet there.